# PHP IMAP get uid after using imap append to add sent mail to imap mailbox

Tags: php, imap

Id like to get the message uid for the message i appended. Here is the code, which is untested and am sure is wrong:

```
$imapStream = imap_open($imapPath,$imapUser,$imapPass);
imap_append($imapStream,$imapPath,$mail->getMailString(),"\\Seen");
$check = imap_check($imapStream);
$uid=imap_uid($imapStream,$check->Nmsgs);
imap_close($imapStream);
```

Basically, what I do after the `imap_append` call is run an `imap_check` to get the message count, then i pass the message count into the `imap_uid` to get the message uid. This can't possibly be right, but this is the first time I've worked with imap and Im just trying to figure this out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, this is wrong -- you have a race condition in there which you will hit if another message arrives between the time you've `APPEND`ed the message and the time you consult the number of messages.

You might want to use the [`UIDPLUS` IMAP extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4315), if available, and consult the `APPENDUID` response code. If this is not available for some reason, your most reliable bet is sending a `UID SEARCH` command with one condition, a `HEADER` match for the `Message-Id` header of the message you've just appended. If you get none or more than one UIDs back, then you're screwed.